What is the way to format array items to fit the style of a Harvard reference?
I am trying to build a Harvard Referencer using Vanilla Javascript. In this referencer, the user inputs information about a book/article and the script manipulates this information to output a Harvard reference like this:

I have managed to create a referencer that can work with a single contributor, but some works have multiple contributors so I have added an additional contributor button in which the user can add other contributors. The trouble is that I can't get the output of additional contributors to match the style of the reference:

The input for the code above is:

function addContributor(name) {
  const newLabel = document.createElement("label");
  const input = document.createElement("input");

  form.insertBefore(newLabel, contributeButton);

  if (name === "last") {
    newLabel.innerHTML = "Last Name(s): ";
    form.insertBefore(input, contributeButton);
  }
  if (name === "first") {
    newLabel.innerHTML = "First Name(s): ";
    form.insertBefore(input, contributeButton);
  }
  contributors.push({
    lastNameInput: input,
    firstNameInput: input,
  });
}

// Add contributor buttons and labels
contributeButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  addContributor("first");
  addContributor("last");
});

// Get, format, and print values of fields into a bib. reference
function printBibRef() {
  const citationComponents = [];

  if (lastName.value) {
    citationComponents.push("(" + lastName.value + ", ");
  }

  if (firstName.value) {
    citationComponents.push(firstName.value[0] + ". ");
  }

  contributors.forEach((contributor) => {
    if (contributor.lastNameInput && contributor.lastNameInput.value) {
      citationComponents.push(contributor.lastNameInput.value + ", ");
    }
    if (contributor.firstNameInput && contributor.firstNameInput.value) {
      citationComponents.push(contributor.firstNameInput.value[0] + ". ");
    }
  });

  }


https://github.com/04092001/Referencer/blob/main/script.js
The output I was expecting would be (Person, F. Person, S)

Please clarify what output format you actually want. Right now, it is hard to tell which part is supposed to be what, with "Person" showing in there multiple times.

Please click [edit], then click the button marked [<>] and produce a [mcve] with mocked input and a description of expected output

Also please use template literals so you can do things like citationComponents.push(\(${lastName.value}, `);`

Also you can push all names into an array and join on , 

Right now, you are pushing first and last names as separate elements into your array, when I enter Firstname1 Lastname1 and Firstname2 Lastname2, that results in ["Lastname1, ", "F. ", "Firstname2", "Lastname2"]. That is probably not a particularly good way to go about this to begin with, especially if you want to list multiple contributors comma-separated, except for an "and" instead of a comma between the last two.

@CBroe. Tryna figure out how to complete this referencer has nearly killed my brain. Would you push all names onto a sub-array and then push that onto the main array? But how would you modify the last name to be first on the array and the first name to be last with only one character? Any pointers would be appreciated!

Yes, I would gather the names first in an array, and create the desired output only at the end.
